# Android Listview with different row views and designs

Tags: android, listview, optimization

The Android List views are optimized by not creating the new UI objects for n number of rows and reusing the Objects with different data. But how can we develop this optimized lists, when coming to the different row views and designs?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean each row has a different layout.  How different are they?  How many different layouts do you have?  If it's just a matter of a couple of controls, then you might consider just setting the visibility of the controls.

Comment: I am having different views for different rows. I have around 10 views which are repeating depending upon the row.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8973288/958370) - there is code snippet for using different views in list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override [getItemViewType()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) in your adapter and return different values for different row views. The ListView is smart enough to pass different views in `getView()` for different view types.